# How can I access a div class within the td which is within the tr which is within the tbody which is within the table

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<tbody id="records">
<tr >
<td>12</td>
<td>20</td>
<td>30</td>
<td>40</td>                       
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10</td>
<td>20</td>
<td>30</td>
<td>40</td>                            
</tr>
</tbody>
```

How can I access into every third table td and check whether that td has digits or string using javascript. In this All my td are having digits.

Comment: Could you please include some attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. That would really help!

Comment: add an id or class property to that element and access it directly.

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
$('#records tr td:nth-child(3)').each(function(){

 // do your check here.

})
```

### [DEMO for understanding](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/Yxq6A/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var check= true;
$('#records tr td:nth-child(3)').each(function(){
if(isNaN($(this).html())){
check=false;
}
});
alert(check);
```

[For Demo Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/7e4py/)